# While Condition used in Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I am able to understand the basic principle on how Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm works. Only thing I am not able to understand is the while loop condition which is as below:

```
while(slow && fast && fast->next){
        slow = slow->next;
    /*Moving fast pointer two steps at a time */
        fast = fast->next->next;
        if(slow == fast){
                loop_found = 1;
                break;
        }

}
```

Since `fast->next` will move fastest and will become NULL in the first place. Why can't we just put `fast->next` in `while` the loop. While doing so will I be missing on some boundary conditions?

```
while(fast->next) instead of  `while(slow && fast && fast->next)`
```

I wrote below code and it worked fine for both even and odd ordered linear linked list. So, Do we need the `fastPtr` condition in the while loop just for the `empty linked list check`. Please enlighten.

```
void linklist::detect()
{
    node * fastPtr = new node;
    node * slwPtr = new node;
    slwPtr = head;
    fastPtr = head;
    while (/*slwPtr!=NULL && fastPtr!=NULL &&*/ fastPtr->next!=NULL)
    {
        fastPtr = fastPtr->next->next;
        slwPtr = slwPtr->next;
        if (fastPtr == slwPtr)
        {
            cout << "Loop Detected\n";
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider an empty linked list where slow and fast is null, we require the null checks in place. We can avoid the slow null check because of what you cited.

```
while(fast && fast->next) //This should do.
```

Considering your solution, we will end up in `Segmentation Fault` because of dereferencing Null Pointers.

The while check is added to check if the node is not NULL as in these scenarios:

- Empty Linked list. `fast = NULL`.
- Linear Linked List i.e with no loops (2 nodes).

  `Consider a linked list 1->2->NULL
  First iteration: fast = 1 and gets modified as fast =NULL
  Second iteration: Segmentation fault for while(fast->next)`

Comment: So it means that the **fast** part is just for the empty linklist check. If that case can be neglected then we are good to go with **while(fast->next)**.

Comment: empty Node check. It can be in two cases. When you have an empty linked list or a linear linked list with no loops.

Comment: Try with both odd and even number of nodes.

Comment: I have put one code in the main question section and it worked for both even and odd. Can you please look into it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What if head is null?

Comment: I got that **head** being **NULL** part. Can you please clarify the 2nd Issue which you mentioned.  **Linear Linked List i.e with no loops**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67668/discussion-between-thepace-and-user1292432).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67669/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-thepace).